# How to evaluate truth of expressions with free variables?

Tags: first-order-logic

I'm learning FOL, and in the book I'm reading, I found an exercise containing a logical expression which should be evaluated to true/false, though I can't see how it would be possible.

The exercise contains these three logical sentences:

$$
a)\: \forall{x}\forall{y}\forall{z} \:[(P(x, y) \: \land \: P(y, z)) \: \supset \: P(x,z)] \\
b)\: \forall{x}\forall{y} \: [(P(x, y) \: \land \: P(y, x)) \: \supset \: (x = y)] \\
c)\: \forall{x}\forall{y} \: [P(a, y) \supset P(x, b)]
$$

The exercise demands to find an interpretation for each sentence, where the sentence itself is false and the other two are true. I think I can do that, but I have a problem with sentence $c$: it contains free variables. How do I evaluate it to true/false, in order to find an interpretation where it is either true or false? It seems wrong to me to simply assume $\forall{a}\forall{b}$ anyway.

Comment: It depends on the details of the semantic specifications of the book. Are *variable assignment* functions used ?

Comment: The book is "Knowledge Representation and Reasoning", an introduction to AI & Machine Learning. This introductory chapter presents FOL in general, describing interpretations and denotations (variable assignment) as well. But the exercise is exactly this, I didn't leave anything out. It doesn't mention defining denotations too, only the interpretation (domain and meaning of P).

Comment: Two possibilities: $a,b$ are (individual) *constants*: in this case, their meaning (their denotation) is fixed by the interpretation; (ii) they are (individual) variables: in this case, we need a variable assignment $v$ to give them a "meaning". The truth value of a formula is fixed for an interpretation and a variable assignment; changing the var assignment may affect the truth value of the formula.

Comment: If Ronald Brachman & Hector Levesque, *Knowledge Representation and Reasoning* (2004), then see page 21.

Comment: Yes, and the exercise is on page 28. Page 21 says "To deal with terms including variables, we also need to start with a variable assignment over D." In other words, to solve the exercise, I'll assign fixed elements to the variables a and b. Still doesn't feel right, since variable assignment is outside the interpretation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a$ and $b$ are individual *variables*: in this case, we need a *variable assignment* function $\mu$ to give them a "meaning". The truth value of a formula is fixed for an interpretation and a variable assignment; changing the variable assignment may affect the truth value of the formula.

See: Ronald Brachman & Hector Levesque, *Knowledge Representation and Reasoning* (2004), page 21 and page 22:

> given an interpretation $\mathcal I$ and a variable assignment $μ$, we say that the formula $α$ is *satisfied* in $\mathcal I$, written $\mathcal I,μ \vDash α$, according to these rules: ...